# select all textboxes except one using javascript

Tags: javascript, selector

What is the simple way to select all text boxes except one with some id using pure javascript?

I am currently using following code for that

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++)
{
    var value = inputs[i];       
    if(value.id != someId)
    {
         // do stuff
    }
}
```

any other ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [new browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll#Browser_compatibility) you may use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) method that works with CSS selectors:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input:not(#id)');
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/nxdqx/

Comment: Great. Thanks. This is really simplified my task